# Problem integrating wxWidgets to Xcode project

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Have a nice day everyone.

I'm a newbie to wxWidgets and i'm trying to build my very first app on XCode with it. However, I have encountered some errors that despite trying different methods, I still can't fix it. If you have any ideas about the problems, please respond to this post. Thank you so much.

Below are my settings for the Xcode project.

[This is for header search paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3OMW.jpg)

[This is for library search paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFv31.jpg)

[Linker flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Bw3.jpg)

[Other C++ flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQpJA.jpg)

This is the error I get after running the program.

```
dyld[2618]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.2.0.dylib
  Referenced from: <7D728CA3-A1C7-34D4-A368-215011A1C936> /Users/nguyenbachtruonggiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wxWidgets-dsxvcfpbquijsadvgnqwcknipupp/Build/Products/Debug/wxWidgets
  Reason: tried: '/Users/nguyenbachtruonggiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wxWidgets-dsxvcfpbquijsadvgnqwcknipupp/Build/Products/Debug/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.2.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/system/introspection/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.2.0.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.2.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.2.0.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
(lldb)
```

If you want to know anything about the project, please let me know. I'm so frustrated with wxWidgets right now   Thank you so much for reading.

Edit: I tried to add all files in the lib folder provided when I installed wxWidgets to the Debug folder of my proj. I also used wx-config --libs and copied all of the flags that appeared on the screen o "Other C flags" in my project Target Build Settings. It worked perfectly fine. You can try with the minimal in the list of samples.

Comment: You need to copy `libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.2.0.dylib` into your application directory in `/Users/nguyenbachtruonggiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wxWidgets-dsxvcfpbquijsadvgnqwcknipupp/Build/Products/Debug/`

Comment: wxWidgets have a `wx-conifg` utility (https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Wx-Config) to help you find all the path of it's include and libraries. If you can find that under the compiled wxWidgets project folder, it may be far more convenience.

Comment: @cpprust thank you for letting me now about this, it does help everything become easier for me

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you for your explanation. I tried this method and it worked perfectly with the minimal.cpp in the samples of wxWidgets. So happy that I can start coding with wxWidgets now. Phew!